# Small case for mac book air that will hold charger and mouse?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware-recommendation, case

I'm looking for a good case for my macbook air 13" that is compact, but still has room for a charger and mouse.  I found [this one](http://www.booqbags.com/us/sleeves/viper-hardcase/VHC13-BLR) like I liked, but the reviews I have found say the pockets aren't big enough to hold a charger.

Has anyone found a good compact case/sleeve that will meet my needs?

Comment: We have a [meta] site to ask just that question - just link back to here so everyone can see the discussion has moved to the discussion area for on and off topic guidelines. Shopping questions are where this one runs afoul of my understanding of the [faq].

Comment: Meta regarding closure if anyone is interested: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/wondering-which-faq-guideline-this-question-violates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Booq bags generally have tolerances that are too tight. My iPad with the Apple case didn't fit in their messenger bag that was made for it.

Since you didn't set a price I would suggest the [City Slicker](http://www.sfbags.com/products/cityslicker-macbookair-case/cityslicker-macbookair.php) case from sfbags.com. I would have bought this bag, but I already had a case for my MBA. I have the version of this case made for the PS Vita and it is an excellent case. There is plenty of room for earbuds, charger, games and extra memory cards. I'm sure there would be enough room in the MBA version of the case for a charger and cables, and by the pictures probably even the DVD drive if you tote that around.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of STM's [Alley Small Laptop Bag](http://www.stmbags.com/catalog/laptop-bags/alley-small-laptop-shoulder-bag/): It holds my MBA 13", the charger, and other small peripherals very handily. STM has also released a more protective [armored laptop bag](http://www.stmbags.com/catalog/laptop-bags/armour-small-hard-shell-laptop-sleeve/).